# How to get a ComboBox to only autocomplete to what is in drop down

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, combobox, autocomplete

Basically what I am trying to do is have it where you can type something into a `ComboBox` and it `autocompletes` to something from it's drop down, but the user shouldn't be able to enter their own entry.

I know that by default if you have `"isEditable"` equal to `true` then it autocompletes on it's own. However you can still enter in whatever you want. I want to prevent this.

This is how I am pulling my `names` in

```
void populateNames()
    {
        nameBox = this.nameTextBox;
        APICaller Caller = new APICaller();
        try
        {
            List<string> listOfNames = Caller.APIGetNames();
            foreach (string a in listOfNames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a);
                nameBox.Items.Add(a);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong: " + e);
        }
        nameBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

and the `ComboBox` in the `XAML`

```
<ComboBox 
        Name="nameTextBox" Height="23" Width="Auto" Margin="10,0,10,97" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsEditable="True"
        PreviewTextInput="tbxPreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="tbxPasting" LostFocus="nameTbxLostFocus" 
        GotFocus="nameTbxGotFocus" PreviewKeyDown="classTextBox_PreviewKeyDown"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your properties tab, set your AutoComplete source to the list of items that populates the combo box. Then, set your AutoCompleteMode to Suggest or SuggestAppend.